# PHPMailer - sending emails with attachments to more than one person and email address downloaded from MySql

Tags: php, database, pdo, phpmailer

First, sorry for my English :)
I have some problem with phpmailer. I want to send emails to multiple people with dedicated attachment to them (pdf). Email address must by downloaded from MySQL. 
But I dont know how can I do it. PDF file have the same name like column 'name' in datebase table. 
For example I have:

- User name: XXX
- PDF name (from ftp): XXX.pdf
- email: somemail@example.com

this is one example, I have a lot of users with lots of pdfs.

Simplifying what I want: user XXX must receive email with XXX.pdf but user YYY must receive email with YYY.pdf.

I dont know if you understand what I mean :)

At this moment I have something like this and i dont know how to assign name to email (dynamically?) in query

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id, name, email FROM users WHERE name ="SomeUserName" '); 
// how to assign name to email??
$stmt->execute();


$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$body             = 'SOME TEXT IN BODY';



$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'name@yourdomain.com');



while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
     $mail->addAttachment("pdf/07.2017/".str_replace('.','_',$row['name']).".pdf"); 
                        $address = $row["email"];
                    }


$mail->AddAddress($address, "SOME TEXT");

$mail->Subject    = "SOME SUBJECT";

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo 'send';
} else {
  echo 'didnt send';
}
```

Comment: Look at the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup all the general information before the while loop.

Then inside your while loop you need to:

1. Add the attachment
2. Set the address for the receiver
3. Send the email
4. [Clear the attachment](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_clearAttachments)
5. [Clear the address for the receiver](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_clearAllRecipients)

A for assigning the variable to your MySQL query

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id, name, email FROM users WHERE name =:name');
$stmt->bindParam(":name", "somename");
```

Obviously `"somename"` can also be a variable like `$_POST['somename']`.